# Authenticate AppSync queries console with Cognito User Pools

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, aws-userpools

I am trying to authenticate Queries playground in AWS AppSync console. I have created User Pool and linked it to the AppSync API, I have also created an App Client in Cognito User Pool (deployed using CloudFormation). It appears under `Select the authorization provider to use for running queries on this page:` in the console.
When I run test query I get:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorType": "UnauthorizedException",
      "message": "Unable to parse JWT token."
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I would expect. There is an option to `Login with User Pools`. The issue is I can't select any `Client ID` and when I choose to insert Client ID manually, anything I enter I get `Invalid UserPoolId format`. I am trying to copy Pool ID from User Pool General settings (format eu-west-2_xxxxxxxxx) but no joy. Btw, I am not using Amplify and I have not configured any Identity Pools.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is the CloudFormation GraphQLApi definition:

```
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-api"
      AuthenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      UserPoolConfig:
        UserPoolId: !Ref UserPoolClient
        AwsRegion: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
        DefaultAction: ALLOW
```

Comment: Sounds like a stupid question but just want to rule out this possibility, how did you link your User Pool to your GraphQL API? Also, is API and User Pool are in the same region?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all, you pointed back to review the CloudFormation yaml and found the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up the stack using CloudFormation I have followed these 2 examples:

https://adrianhall.github.io/cloud/2018/04/17/deploy-an-aws-appsync-graphql-api-with-cloudformation/

https://gist.github.com/adrianhall/f330a10451f05a529680f32978dddb64

Turns out they both (same author) have an issue in them in the section where ApiGraphQL is defined. This:

```
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-api"
      AuthenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      UserPoolConfig:
        UserPoolId: !Ref UserPoolClient
        AwsRegion: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
        DefaultAction: ALLOW
```

Should be:

```
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-api"
      AuthenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      UserPoolConfig:
        UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool
        AwsRegion: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
        DefaultAction: ALLOW
```

Thank you @Myz for pointing me back to review the whole CF yaml file